# TypeError: resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a function that will read a file and depending upon success or failure in reading it will call the resolve or reject function. Below is the code that I have written.

```
let fs = require('fs');

const FILE_NAME = './assets/pies.json';

let pieRepo = {
    get: function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports = pieRepo;
```

However when I run "npm start" it throws the below error

```
/workingdirectory/repos/pieRepo.js:12
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                ^

TypeError: resolve is not a function
    at /workingdirectory/repos/pieRepo.js:12:17
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

I am using version 16.11.0 of node.

Comment: resolve() and reject() are parameters of a Promise, that you're not using on your code sample

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is with the way you are trying to resolve promise. The Resolve & Reject Functions are available within Promise

```
let fs = require("fs");

const FILE_NAME = "YOUR PATH TO FILE";

let pieRepo = {
  get: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });
  },
};

module.exports = pieRepo;
```

You can further read about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1):

Resolve and reject are functions available in promises.

Replace your code with this:

```
let fs = require('fs');

const FILE_NAME = './assets/pies.json';

let pieRepo = {
    get: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(FILE_NAME, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        });
    },
};

module.exports = pieRepo;
```

Now, you can await the `get` function.

If this were my project though, the code would look like this:

```
let fs = require('fs/promises');

const FILE_NAME = './assets/pies.json';

let pieRepo = {
    get: async () => {
        try {
            const data = await fs.readFile(FILE_NAME);
            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err.message);
        }
    },
};

module.exports = pieRepo;
```

If you want to promisify `fs.readFile`, you can, but promisified versions of `fs` functions are available through `fs/promises`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know precisely where you're getting this code from on pluralsight, I hit the same thing.
Your original code is fine...IF and ONLY IFF  you have removed the
//let pies = pieRepo.get();

In your index.js.  Otherwise it's making an invalid call and is going to barf.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Promise, here is a very simple example:

```
test() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (1 === 1) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        reject(false)
      }
    })
  }
```