# use node module in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to import and use the node module in js.

The module i want to use is this.

https://github.com/contentful/contentful-resolve-response

I ran it like the example, but encountered an error.

1. I installed the module with the npm command.

```
npm install contentful-resolve-response --save
```

2. Create an index.js file and import that module.

```
import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'
```

3. Use module like github example

```
var items = resolveResponse(response)
```

4. Bundled with webpack.
5. I put the bundled js file in html and tried to run it.

The error phrase is:
Uncaught TypeError: n(...).resolveResponse is not a function

Is the module not properly imported?

---

package.json dependency

```
"dependencies": {
    "contentful-resolve-response": "^1.3.12"
  },
```

index.js

```
import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'

var response = {
  items: [
    {
      someValue: 'wow',
      someLink: { sys: { type: 'Link', linkType: 'Entry', id: 'suchId' } }
    }
  ],
  includes: {
    Entry: [
      { sys: { type: 'Entry', id: 'suchId' }, very: 'doge' }
    ]
  }
};

var items = resolveResponse(response) <- **error**
```

---

*Edited

The import statement was wrong, so I fixed it.

`import * as contentfulReserve from 'contentful-resolve-response'`

to

`import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'`

and call

`var res = resolveResponse(response)`

But this time I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`
error occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: resolve is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951414/typeerror-resolve-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @Delanovanlonden - That doesn't appear to be remotely related.

Comment: I believe you are importing all exports from contentful-resolve-response under an alias, try `contentfulResolve.resolveResponse`

Comment: Regarding your edit, you have a typo in your import statement.

Comment: In contentful-resolve-response.js

`export default resolveResponse;`

therefore

`import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'`

has been modified to but
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')` error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisk from the import statement and then call the function with the name that you used for the import.

```
import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'

var response = {
  items: [
    {
      someValue: 'wow',
      someLink: { sys: { type: 'Link', linkType: 'Entry', id: 'suchId' } }
    }
  ],
  includes: {
    Entry: [
      { sys: { type: 'Entry', id: 'suchId' }, very: 'doge' }
    ]
  }
};

var items = resolveResponse(response)
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`
error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: n(...).resolveResponse is not a function` alludes to the fact that the function `resolveResponse` is not a defined function in the scope that you are trying to use it.

The thing that sticks out to me is the fact that your import statement imports all the exports of the library under an alias `contentfulResorve` which means if you would like to access the `resolveResponse` function from that library you must access it through the alias as `contentfulResorve.resolveResponse`.

```js
import * as contentfulResorve from 'contentful-resolve-response'
/* SOME CODE HERE */
var items = contentfulResorve.resolveResponse(response)
```

However, looks like the default export on the library is the function you intend to use which means you can write it the following way

```js
import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'
/* SOME CODE HERE */
var items = resolveResponse(response)
```

Comment: i try `import resolveResponse from 'contentful-resolve-response'` but
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`
error occurs.